# Application Slow after a couple of uses

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, vaadin

I created an application that works perfect in my computer but when I uploaded it to start server tests it becomes very slow, specially after a couple of uses (the first minutes work fine)...It even becomes unresponsive, as I move through a treetable a form should be updated from the database but stops working after a while...

I'm using an Amazon EC2 Linux server and a MySQL database...I checked if the connections to the database is what failed, but I'm using no more than 7 out of 150 max connections to the database.

Is this a common problem?

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!!!

Note: This is a copy of an internal vaadin forum thread: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4816326 ...Hope is not against the forum rules to do this...

Comment: Its probably a memory leak. You may want to provide some code samples of where you think the problem could be occuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a memory leak in your application somewhere that your computer is able to sustain, but your server is not. I would suggest trying some load testing on another machine and see what actions are causing it to spin out.

You can have a look at this SO answer to see how to do that:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227692/460802